# Get database names based on a query from the tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a list of databases that have the same schema. 
I would like to get back a list of all database names that contain a certain entry in one of the tables.

Example: All the databases contain a "user" table. I would like to get a list of all the databases that contain a user with id "john". Can someone point me in the direction of how I should go about this.

PS: I don't want to write a script to do this. I want to be able to do this just in MYSQL

Comment: You won't be able to do this in a single SQL statement, but you can build an SQL script or procedure, as opposed to needing to run any client code.

Comment: Could you provide an example MYSQL script to achieve something like this?

Comment: Duplicates a near identical question about a week ago,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49830215/5870171

Comment: this was already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49830215/5870171 ::aamir::

Comment: The answer is not correct and returns an error saying the number of columns in select statement does not match.

Comment: That query uses SELECT * to get all columns from similarly named and defined tables in multiple databases. If you get an error saying that the number of columns does not match then it implies that the columns of your 'user' tables do not match in number. You could just adjust the query to include only column names that you know are common to ALL your tables.